# HTML5 -> Java Server

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket

Unfortunately for this question, I can't really post my "Attempt" at solving this issue, because I'm not sure what the issue is to begin with, here recently I've been developing a small networking wrapper for gaming servers, me and a few friends have been testing it using C#/Java clients and it's been working out great; However I decided that I wanted to try something new and mess with the (Sortof) new HTML5. I've seen examples of games that are written in HTML5 and look absolutely amazing, an example of this would be the `Runescape` browser based game which has an HTML5 version. More information [here](http://www.runescape.com/beta/html5).

I'm only interested in working with 2D games, however I thought that instead of using a Java Applet (Like I used to) I could learn how to do things in HTML5 and have a true web-based application. The problem isn't so much learning HTML5 as it is understanding its networking.

Currently for my server I'm using Netty, which is a Java NIO framework, however I've been studying and sources claim that HTML can't connect directly to a standard TCP socket and instead require a WebSocket. I did some searching into netty for a websocket and it seems supported, information located [here](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/server/WebSocketServer.java).

My only question, in which I can't find any information on is sending the data in a manner that the server will be able to read it. I'm using the [DataInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) class to read data on the server side, which requires special encoding to create "Blocks" of networked data, as-well as some customized encoding for primitive data-types, and a custom encoding for UTF data-types. I wrote my own output stream for our C# client API, however with HTML I'm at a complete loss.

I can't find any information about sending data, or customizing the data sent into blocks, or anything. C# made it really simple with the use of it's [BinaryWriter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/binarywriter.cs) class, but with HTML5 I'm just at a complete lack of resources to learn from, or my google-fu really needs to be worked on.

Comment: take a look at this http://binaryjs.com/

Comment: @vtortola - Very nice link.